# Check for overlapping shapes in WPF

Tags: wpf, layout, shapes

I have a set of shapes which need to be drawn on top of each other. I need to re-order them such that the smallest shape gets drawn last (i.e. it will be closest to the user). Is there any way to check whether a shape overlappes (encloses and/or intersects) another shape. I know there is a method in `Rect` structure called `Contains` which checks whether there is an object within it. Is there a similar method or a way to simulate it on Shapes in WPF? Thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers,

Nilu

Answer (score 5):

You could probably use the [`Geometry.FillContainsWithDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.fillcontainswithdetail.aspx) method. Its name is ill-chosen IMHO, but the description is clear :

> Returns a value that describes the intersection between the current geometry and the specified geometry.

I have successfully used it for collision testing before, so it should work for you too...

Comment: thanks Thomas, I will try it out :) Although I think I might have to create Geometry objects corresponding to each of the shapes.

Comment: This was a helpful hint! I've seen this method but discarded it – but I missed its return value which gives the real information. Note that `Intersects` ends where `FullyContains` begins, so check for both to test for "partially of fully overlapping".