# How to simulate a sensor

Tags: c#, wpf, simulation, plc

So I am working on a project which requires me to do some hardware simulations. Let's say I have a belt filled with sensors. Just like this one. 
[image]

When the `obj` reaches the sensor it should trigger the sensor which in this case the state of the sensor becomes `False` (otherwise True). I am working with PLC so when it's `false` or `true` I write a bit to the PLC. I have this part covered though. Just need help triggering the sensor(s).

Just like so 
[image]

Notice the color of the first sensor from the right side turns gray which means it detected an object so now the sensor is `false` (turned off in other words). Just as the `obj` passes by the sensor returns to its default state which is `true`

To do this I had the following in mind.

- Something with collision when the sensor detects an object closing by
- Instead of a straight beam I could have a region and when the object lands in this region the sensor triggers.
- I could work with timers (I have tried this) but it gives me the feeling that I am actually cheating. So It's not very preferable.

I am working with WPF and C#. Would someone please show me some working sample code I could built upon that.

Thanks for your time!

**Update #1** Based on the comment below

I have classes of the following with proberties.

- Sensor (position, size)
- The object which travels along the belt. (position, size)

The simulator I am working on should view both the behavior and visual representation. Just like the diagrams. For testing purposes I have now a simple eclipse. As soon as the object closes by the color of the eclipse changes. It changes back as soon as the object passses by. Doing this in timer.

The objects traveling are always in a shape of a rectangular, but may differ in sizes. The user is able to choose between 2 sort of objects. One is as big as what  the diagram now shows, and the other is little bigger which might cause to trigger sensor earlier.

Comment: How does the simulator work? Well your explanation of the original hardware implementation is very clear, but it does not seem to tell us how the simulated version is doing at the moment. For example, do you have an class representing the physical object, which probably has properties like size, position etc? Does your application needs to show it visually, just like the diagrams you showed? Or does it just need to show the behavior? Is the physical object always rectangular? Information like this will be crucial for us to think something out. The way it is now, it's still too broad.

Comment: @Jai I updated the post. Any other information, please ask away. I will update the post if required.

Comment: @user3641381 I am making a sample app now.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan if you could do that.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3641381 Check updated answer

Comment: @user3641381 see my new answer for a generalized approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [HitTesting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097(v=vs.100).aspx).

And then you need to set a `DependencyProperty` something like `CollisionDetected` to `True`.

Then apply a `DataTrigger` to your `Beam` xaml to change its `Style/BackgroundColor` etc.

```
   <uc:BeamControl>
        <uc:BeamControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="BeamControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CollisionDetected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </uc:BeamControl.Style>
    </uc:BeamControl>
```

*********************** New Addition with code************************

In this working solution I have used an Attached Property. I have kept everything simple to focus on core issue.

[image: Beam animation output]

***Window2.xaml***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAnimation.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAnimation"
        Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="900">
    <Canvas>
        <Path local:Window2.MovingObjectPos="{Binding (Canvas.Left), ElementName=ElpObj}"  Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50" Width="39" Data="M19.5,0.5 L19.5,147.5 M0.5,148.5 L38.5,148.5 L38.5,169.5 L0.5,169.5 z">

        </Path>
        <Path local:Window2.MovingObjectPos="{Binding (Canvas.Left), ElementName=ElpObj}"  Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="50" Width="39" Data="M19.5,0.5 L19.5,147.5 M0.5,148.5 L38.5,148.5 L38.5,169.5 L0.5,169.5 z">

        </Path>
        <Path local:Window2.MovingObjectPos="{Binding (Canvas.Left), ElementName=ElpObj}"  Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="50" Width="39" Data="M19.5,0.5 L19.5,147.5 M0.5,148.5 L38.5,148.5 L38.5,169.5 L0.5,169.5 z">

        </Path>
        <Path local:Window2.MovingObjectPos="{Binding (Canvas.Left), ElementName=ElpObj}"  Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Top="50" Width="39" Data="M19.5,0.5 L19.5,147.5 M0.5,148.5 L38.5,148.5 L38.5,169.5 L0.5,169.5 z">

        </Path>
        <Ellipse x:Name="ElpObj" Fill="Pink" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57" Height="51" Canvas.Left="701" Canvas.Top="115">
            <Ellipse.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" To="50" By="-2.0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Ellipse.Triggers>
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

***Window2.xaml.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfAnimation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public static double GetMovingObjectPos(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (double)obj.GetValue(MovingObjectPosProperty);
        }

        public static void SetMovingObjectPos(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(MovingObjectPosProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MovingObject.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MovingObjectPosProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MovingObjectPos", typeof(double), typeof(Window2), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(MovingObjectPosChanged)));


        private static void MovingObjectPosChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double leftOfMovingObject = (double) e.NewValue ;
            Path beam = (Path) d;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Left = " + e.NewValue.ToString());

            double leftOfBeam = Canvas.GetLeft(beam);
            double widthOfBeam = 20.0;

            if (leftOfMovingObject > leftOfBeam && leftOfMovingObject < leftOfBeam + widthOfBeam)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hit >>>>> = " + e.NewValue.ToString());

                beam.Fill = Brushes.Gray;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Any other solution in mind  if `beam` did not exist..? Such as collision between the `object`and the `eclipse`

Comment: BeamControl can be a `Line` shape as well.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan  Do I understand this correctly? WPF hit testing only when a mouse is clicked? If so, this is not what I am asking.

Comment: @user3641381 No, you can use it anywhere, as long the objects are subclasses of `System.Windows.Media.Visual`.

Comment: @Jai Could you provide a link or some sample code I could have a look at on how to achieve this without using mouse clicks.

Comment: @user3641381 Simple check the coordinates of the object's bounding rectangle and the censor's rectangle, and check if there is collision.

Answer (score 1):

I have refined my old answer using `Task`, and considering unlimited moving objects.

It uses actual [HitTesting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097(v=vs.100).aspx).

1. Create a `UserControl` for Beam object. This is needed to initiate `Task` immediately after `Loading`. It contains a DP for the containing `Panel`.

#### BeamControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfAnimation.BeamControl" ... 
             Height="300" Width="39">
        <Path Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="39" Data="M19.5,0.5 L19.5,147.5 M0.5,148.5 L38.5,148.5 L38.5,169.5 L0.5,169.5 z"/>
</UserControl>
```

#### BeamControl.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfAnimation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BeamControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BeamControl : UserControl
    {

        Path _beamPath;

        public Panel Sensor
        {
            get { return (Panel)GetValue(SensorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SensorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Sensor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SensorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Sensor", typeof(Panel), typeof(BeamControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        private  double left;
        private double top;

        public BeamControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += BeamControl_Loaded;             
        }

        void BeamControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _beamPath = this.Content as Path;

            left = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
            top = Canvas.GetTop(this);

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    _doDetection();
                }

            });
        }

        void _doDetection()
        {
            // 200 is the height of the beam, you can change it
            for (double i = top; i < 200; i = i + 1)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                Point pt = new Point(left + 20.0, i);

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Sensor,
                        new HitTestFilterCallback((o) =>
                        {
                            if (o is Ellipse)
                            {
                                _beamPath.Fill = Brushes.DarkKhaki;
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Detected ! " + o.GetType().ToString());
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pt.ToString());
                                return HitTestFilterBehavior.Stop;
                            }
                            else
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(o.GetType().ToString());

                            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
                        }),
                        new HitTestResultCallback((result) => { return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue; }),
                        new PointHitTestParameters(pt));
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAnimation.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="Window5" Height="303.383" Width="622.556">
    <Canvas>
        <local:BeamControl Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="50" Sensor="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>

        <local:BeamControl Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="50" Sensor="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>

        <Ellipse x:Name="ElpObj" Fill="Pink" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57" Height="51" Canvas.Left="548" Canvas.Top="114">
            <Ellipse.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" To="50" By="-0.5" Duration="0:0:20"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Ellipse.Triggers>
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Run the application *Without Debugging*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you intend to follow MVVM, but either case you can probably try doing this way:

For the visual part, you can use a `Canvas`, but any other Panels would probably work. Canvas would allow you to use `Canvas.Left` and stuff like that, and all your positioning would be probably based on `System.Windows.Point` values, instead of relative positioning, anyway.

The rest of the things can be drawn with one of the `System.Window.Shapes.Shape` subclasses. The two bars probably `Rectangle`, for beam would be `Line`, and for sensor probably an `Ellipse` or a `Rectangle`.

The beam objects should have `Visibility` bound to some property in your ViewModel (or simply code behind if not using MVVM). The `Stroke` property of the beams and `Fill` property of the sensors should be bound as well.

I am not sure how sensor size would affect anything, probably it could mean the beam could be very wide? If it does affect, bind the `Width` and `Height` as well. Also remember to bind beam's `StrokeThickness` if sensor size matters.

For the object, you would use `Rectangle` again. Again, do the necessary binding. The new binding would be `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, so that you know the position.

Now we need to animate the object. Since your have the position through binding, you can change the position in the source property - the binding engine will do the render changes for you. You can use a timer for the movement of the object.

Now we need to find collision. One way is to calculate it code behind, which would be done every time the object position changes. There is another way to do it, because you are using Canvas. Read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388681/check-for-overlapping-shapes-in-wpf). All you need to do is to convert the underlying `Geometry` instance for the object and beams (through `myobject.RenderedGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(beam)`).

There are certainly many other ways to do this. I just hope I managed to provide a direction to start your project.